# Postgres, copy to a csv file

Tags: postgresql

On Postgres, I want to load a select query into a csv file. But in the CSV file I want to put some values, that doesn't appear in the query, how do I do that? It's like:

```
select id, name, email
```

And then have a Date, which I want to set default in every line. So the csv will be like:

```
id,name,email,date
```

Comment: Which Postgres version ?

Comment: You can revise [using sed to add new column into CSV file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/446601/how-to-add-date-in-the-last-column-in-csv-file-in-unix) and [using copy with program](https://paquier.xyz/postgresql-2/postgres-9-3-feature-highlight-copy-tofrom-program/)

Answer (score 2):

Just select the additional value:

```
select id, name, email, current_date as "date"
from the_table;
```

or

```
select id, name, email, date '2018-10-09' as "date"
from the_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can COPY or \copy from an arbitrary query if you put parentheses around it.

```
\copy (select id, name, email, now() as "date" from example) to file.csv with (format csv)
```